# "too much recursion" jquery error

Tags: jquery, recursion

Trying to create a background-image slideshow and am getting this error...  This is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j( function(){
    var bgArr = [ 'sample1.jpg','sample2.jpg','sample3.jpg' ];
    function backgroundSlide(i) {
             $j("#home_sub_banner").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i++]+")");
             if (i == bgArr.length) i = 0;
             var st = setTimeout(arguments.callee(i), 1000);
    }
backgroundSlide(0)

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `arguments.callee(i)`, you are *calling* `arguments.callee` and passing its result (if any) to `setTimeout`.  This results in infinite recursion.

You need pass `setTimeout` and anonymous function that calls `arguments.callee` later, like this:

```
var me = arguments.callee;
setTimeout(function() { me(i); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is creating an infinite recrusive method call to `backgroundSlide`.

Why don't you try a different implementation using setInterval instead?

Something like this:

```
var bgArr = [ 'sample1.jpg','sample2.jpg','sample3.jpg' ];
var currentBg = 0;
function backgroundSlide() {
         $j("#home_sub_banner").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[currentBg++]+")");
         if (currentBg == bgArr.length) currentBg = 0;
}
setInterval(backgroundSlide, 1000);
```

*PS: Above Code not tested but you'll get the gist of it.*